# creating a new column in bigquery sql using another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Please consider this example dataset

```
#standardSQL
WITH abc AS (
  SELECT 1234 id, 'Aug' month, 'P' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, 'Sept', 'P' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3456, 'Aug', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3456, 'Sept', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4567, 'Aug', 'P' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4567, 'Sept', 'D' 
)
SELECT *, (max(case when value = 'P' then 1 end) , max(case when value = 'D' then 2 end))  as grade
FROM abc
group by id, month, value
ORDER BY id
```

The result I get is

```
    
Row  id     month   value   grade._field_1  grade._field_2
1   1234    Aug      P            1             null
2   1234    Sept     P            1             null
3   3456    Aug      D            null            2
4   3456    Sept     D            null            2
5   4567    Aug      P            1             null
6   4567    Sept     D            null            2
```

while my desired result is

```
Row  id     month   value   grade   
1   1234    Aug      P        1             
2   1234    Sept     P        1             
3   3456    Aug      D        2       
4   3456    Sept     D        2            
5   4567    Aug      P        1             
6   4567    Sept     D        2
```

Can anyone help me update the code, please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to just use a single `CASE` expression here:

```sql
SELECT id, month,
       CASE value WHEN 'P' THEN 1 WHEN 'D' THEN 2 END AS grade
FROM abc
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: sure, I would like to know if can we do it without MAX statement as well? what is the significance of MAX here?

Comment: why would you delete the updated solution? :(

Comment: Your use of `GROUP BY` and `MAX` totally threw me off, when all you needed was a simple `CASE` expression.